# Vector subscription out of range error c++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to create a simulation of conway's game of life.
I keep getting a "vector subscript out of range" error after about 300 generation and I don't understand the reason. From what I could gather it's caused by using an invalid index. The most likely section is the first part of the draw function where I find empty rows and replace them with "\n" to save time.
I've started learning to code not too long ago so I may be making baby mistakes.

Edit: visual studio point the error after the third for loop in the frame function, on `if (emptyRows[m] == i)`

Here's the full code :

```
#include <array>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

const int WIDTH = 150;
const int HEIGHT = 50;

bool table[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
bool tableNew[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

std::string buffer;

int total;
int counter = 0;

std::vector<int> emptyRows;

int numberOfNeighbours(int Y, int X) {
    if (X == 0 || Y == 0 || X == WIDTH || Y == HEIGHT)
        return 2;
    total = 0;
    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j++) {
            if (table[X + j][Y + i] == true)
                total++;
        }
    }
    total -= table[X][Y];
    return total;
}

void draw() {
    srand((int)time(0));
    int m = 0;
    bool check = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            if (table[j][i] == 1)
                check = 1;
            }

        if (check == 0)
            emptyRows.push_back(i);
        else
            check = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        if (emptyRows.size() >= 1) {
            if (emptyRows[m] == i) {
                buffer.append("\n");
                m++;
                continue;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            if (table[j][i] == 1) buffer.push_back('#');
            else buffer.push_back(' ');
        }
        buffer.append("\n");
    }
    std::cout << buffer;
    std::cout << std::endl << "Generazione numero:" << counter;

    emptyRows.erase(emptyRows.begin(), emptyRows.end());
    buffer.erase(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
    m = 0;
}

void reset() {
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            table[j][i] = tableNew[j][i];
        }
    }
}

void logic() {
    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            int k = numberOfNeighbours(i, j);

            if (table[j][i] == 0 && k == 3)
                tableNew[j][i] = 1;

            else if (table[j][i] == 1 && k != 2 && k != 3)
                tableNew[j][i] = 0;

            else
                tableNew[j][i] = table[j][i];
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            if ((rand() % 2) == 1)
                table[j][i] = 1;
        }
    }

    while (true) {

        counter++;

        draw();

        logic();

        reset();

        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I keep getting a "vector subscript out of range" error after about 300 generation and I don't understand the reason.* -- The reason is that you have one or more logical errors in your program.  Also, since that error occurs with Visual C++, assuming this is what you're using, the Visual Studio debugger will show you exactly where the out-of-bounds access is occurring.

Comment: `numberOfNeighbours()` is full of obvious out-of-bounds accesses. After all, it should be obvious that last valid index in horizontal or vertical axis is `WIDTH-1` and `HEIGHT-1`, accordingly.

Comment: I'm aware of the issues in the neighbours funcion bit since I'm planning to implement a wrap arountd for the edges, I used an of to make the edges static.

Comment: If `m` is ever bigger than `emptyrows.size()`, that will throw this error. You might want to check for that.